# PHP Search form is testing only last row of the database

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to create a search facility for a website. the website contains text posts so the database has a table post_record with field post_id, post_title, post_href and post_content.

now the working is when a user enters any search keyword in search field, that keyword is being tested against all the post titles and post contents and where it matches it should return all those rows. Following is the code for it. the issue is its returning only the last row of the databse.

```
<table class="s_table">
<?php
require_once'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['search_btn']))
{
    $mes = " ";
    $search_key =" ";
    $search_key = ($_POST['search_field']);
    try
    {
        if(empty($search_key) && $search_key != " ")
        {
            echo $mes = "Enter the keyword you want to search.";
        }
        else
        {               
            $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post_record WHERE post_title LIKE '%".$search_key."%' OR post_content LIKE '%".$search_key."%'");
            $result->execute();
            $count=$result->rowCount();
            $datas = $result->fetchAll();
            if(!$count)
            {
                echo $mes = "No Result found. Try another keyword for search.";
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($datas as $data)                                           
                {
                echo "
                    <tr><td><b><u><a href='".$data['post_href']."'>".$data['post_title']."</a></b></u></td></tr><br>
                    <tr><td class='s_cont'>".$data['post_content']."</tr></td><br><br>";

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $mes = "Something Went Wrong! try again";
        header("location:index.php");
    }
}

$conn = null;
```

?>

Everything is working fine except the thing that it is displaying only last row of the database.

Right now database has 3 posts and for testing purpose i tried a keyword that i know is common in all the post contents but its not working. only last row the database is being fetched and tested.

Comment: I recommend adding the search qry to the sql using `LIKE` - I think the strpos is what the cause is..

Comment: Let the database indeed to the heavly lifting... `SELECT * FROM post_record WHERE post_title LIKE '%searchterm%' OR  post_content LIKE '%searchterm%'`  and remove the stripos from php

Comment: humm.. thnx. i ll try this then get back to you..thnx for the response..

Comment: what number displays the rowCount()?

Comment: @Disturb it returns 3

Answer (score 0):

`if(empty($search_key) && $search_key != " ")` this condition is wrong
Both are different things which wont get true ever.
you are testing if its empty and then u r testing if its not empty
Both in same if condition

Comment: thnx for pointing out but its not the issue as i am using html5 and search button will not take effect if search box is empty so its not the issue.

Comment: can you try your code by removing `if(empty($search_key) && search_key != " ")       {         echo $mes = "Enter the keyword you want to search.";      }        else        { ` if $search_key is not a problem according to you?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use procedual functions but I encounter a problem like this with the `mysqi_fetch_array()`, so your problem might be that `fetchAll()` is moving the cursor to the last record. Try to remove that function or use `mysql_data_seek($datas , 0)` before the `foreach()` .